# Error when trying to refer to widgets in orginal layout after setContentView

Tags: android, listview, nullpointerexception

I wanted to programatically put a listview into my android application. So, when the user clicks a button, it will `setContentView(listview)`. When the user selects the item, it will `setContentView(R.layout.main)`. However, when I try to refer to layout widgets inside of the orginal layout, `R.layout.main`, I receive a `javaNullPointerException`. Can someone help to clarify this issue for me?

I am using an `onItemClickListener` for user selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it makes sense what are you trying to do here:

```
setContentView(listview)
```

the listview should simply be part of your layout.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `setContentView` to handle a selection, launch a new `Activity` with `startActivity()` or `startActivityForResult()`. Using `findViewById()` works by searching the current content view tree (your layout.xml file) for a widget with the ID that you specify. Once you set a new content view, it will be searching whatever XML layout you specified for the new content view.

Comment: Yes! Incredibly helpful. I realize my error now. Thank you for your quick reply.